# How can you improve/configure que VS Code preview?. WinEdt and TeXstudio preview is much better

Tags: texstudio, winedt, vscode, latex-workshop

Comparing WinEdt vs TeXstudio vs VSCode(with LaTeX Workshop).

I love the autocomplete of VS Code, but the preview of VS Code is a little fuzzy/blurr comparing to WinEdt and TeXstudio.

How can I improve/configure que VS Code (with LaTeX Workshop) preview?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might want to give [LaTeX Previewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mjpvs.latex-previewer) for VS Code a try.